# ItemChange not called on qgraphicsItem despites flags

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

Probably something simple but I cannot get it to work:
I have overloaded the `itemChange()` method on a class derived from `QGraphicsItem`.

The code is as follows:

```
QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value) 
{
cerr << "renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:" << int(change) <<endl;
return value;
}
```

I also set the following flags:

```
gitem->setFlag( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable );
gitem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
gitem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
```

The output when running is as follows: (don't pay any attention on the total number of events, I have different instanciation of my derived class)

```
renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:2
renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:2
renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:21
renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:22
renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:21
renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:21
renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:2
renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:12
renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:2
renderer_scene::item_pos_change!:12
```

Meaning that my function gets called when the item visibulity is changed(change==2 and 12 when done), which is in accordance with my code, when the flags are changed (==21 and == 22 when done).

But When I move my item: nothing.

There are many stranges things happening:
1) I would expect to get the change values in pairs: Flags change followed by flags have changed (21 followed by 22)and (2 followed by 12). Some "flag change" are not even followed by the matching "flag have changed". This is maybe indicating that some of my flags setting is ignored which may be my problem... but why?

2) The flag `QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges` does seem to imply `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable`. when I set `QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges` alone the object becomes movable... why?

3) and finally I don't get any call for change position when I do move the item.

What's going on??

I am running qt 4.8.4 on linux FC16.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Forget about it! a make clean +qmake + make fixed it!  No clue why, but clearly not related to the code stated here.

Sorry!